# Nested BottomNavigationBar results in Duplicate appBar

Tags: flutter, dart, bottomnavigationview

I've got a nested `BottomNavigationBar` which allows me to create a stack within each item. This allows me to pop back to the original page within a stack. But after pushing to another page the `appBar` is duplicated. If I remove the original `appBar`, I am left without an `appBar` on the landing page. If I remove the destination `appBar` I lose the arrow to pop back.

So I'm thinking I should either try to;

- Programmatically remove the first `appBar` when pushing to the
  destination page,
- Remove the destination `appBar` and somehow get the original `appBar`
  to inherit the behaviour of the destination `appBar`.

Are either of these approaches sensible? If so what's the best way to do it? Or should I adopt an entirely different approach? Is there a way to have both a permanent `BottomnavigationBar` and `appBar`?

Here's the main code which houses the nested `BottomNavigationBar`;

```
class TabsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabsScreenState createState() => _TabsScreenState();
}

class _TabsScreenState extends State<TabsScreen> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final _home = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  final _messages = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
      //some stuff
       ),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _currentIndex,
        children: <Widget>[
          Navigator(
            key: _home,
            onGenerateRoute: (route) => MaterialPageRoute(
              settings: route,
              builder: (context) => MainPage(),
            ),
          ),
          Navigator(
            key: _messages,
            onGenerateRoute: (route) => MaterialPageRoute(
              settings: route,
              builder: (context) => Messages(),
            ),
          ),     
          ),     
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (val) => _onTap(val, context),
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.message),
            title: Text('Messages'),
          ),          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onTap(int val, BuildContext context) {
    if (_currentIndex == val) {
      switch (val) {
        case 0:
          _home.currentState.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
          break;
        case 1:
          _messages.currentState.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
          break;        
        default:
      }
    } else {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _currentIndex = val;
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the code which pushes to the destination page;

```
  onSwipeUp: () {
              Navigator.push(
              context,
              PageTransition(
                type: PageTransitionType.downToUp,
                child: HomeReply(),
              )
          );
        },
```

And here's the destination code:

```
class HomeReply extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeReplyState createState() => new _HomeReplyState();
}

class _HomeReplyState extends State<HomeReply> {

  @override
  void initState(){}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
           Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                    title: Text(
                      "Back to " + "'" + originalTitle + "'",
                    ),
                  ),
                body: ReplyStage(),          
       );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an entirely different approach using Flutters Nested Navigators plugin;

https://github.com/n0vah/nested_navigators